# Sending "?" and "=" characteres in the query string with RESTEasy

Tags: rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I am creating REST API in my application with RESTEasy:

```java
@GET
@Path("/api")
public Response getData(@QueryParam("from") String from, 
                        @Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest)
                        throws ProtocolException, MalformedURLException, IOException {

    System.out.println("from: " + from);

    ...
}
```

This code belongs to give data for following API:

```
http://localhost:8080/LynkBeta/f/query?from=search?q=developer
```

I am getting only the following value from the query parameter when I print it:

```
search?q
```

But the actual value is:

```
search?q=developer
```

The query parameter contains *an equal to* symbol (`=`). It works fine without it. I know that definitely I am missing something here.

How to handle this kind of values? What I need to include to handle this?

I researched bit, but there is no straight forward answer for my search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

To send `search?q=developer` as a value of a query parameter, this value must be URL encoded. So, `search?q=developer` will become `search%3Fq%3Ddeveloper`.

### Query string

According to the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4), the query string is defined as following:

> [**3.4.  Query**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)
>
> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
> data in the path component, serves to identify a
> resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority
> (if any).  The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI. [...]

Characters such as `?` (used to start the query string), `&` (used to separate the query parameters) and `=` (used to associate the parameter with its value) are [reserved](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).

If you need to send such characteres as *values* of query string parameters, they need to be URL encoded. For more details on when the encoding is necessary, check the section [2.4 When to Encode or Decode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4) of the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4).

### URL Encoding

URL encoding is also known as percent enconding:

> [**2.1.  Percent-Encoding**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)
>
> A percent-encoding mechanism is used to represent a data octet in a
> component when that octet's corresponding character is outside the
> allowed set or is being used as a delimiter of, or within, the
> component.  A percent-encoded octet is encoded as a character
> triplet, consisting of the percent character "%" followed by the two
> hexadecimal digits representing that octet's numeric value.  For
> example, "%20" is the percent-encoding for the binary octet
> "00100000" (ABNF: %x20), which in US-ASCII corresponds to the space
> character (SP). [...]

And many languages support it. Here are examples in Java and JavaScript:

- **Java:** use the [`URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class:

```java
String param = "search?q=developer";
String url = "http://localhost:8080/LynkBeta/f/query?from=" + 
    URLEncoder.encode(param, "UTF-8");
```

- **JavaScript:** use the [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function:

```js
var param = "search?q=developer";
var url = "http://localhost:8080/LynkBeta/f/query?from=" + 
    encodeURIComponent(param);
```

### Encoded parameters with JAX-RS

Consider, for example, you are requesting `http://example.com/api/query?biz=search%3Fq%3Ddeveloper`.

By default, when using the [`@QueryParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) annotation, JAX-RS will URL decode query parameters:

```java
@GET
@Path("/foo")
public Response someMethod(@QueryParam("biz") String biz) {
    ...
}
```

So, the value of the `biz` parameter will be `search?q=developer`.

If you need to receive the parameters URL encoded, used the [`@Encoded`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Encoded.html) annotation:

```java
@GET
@Path("/foo")
public Response someMethod(@QueryParam("biz") @Encoded String biz) {
    ...
}
```

Now, the value of the `biz` parameter will be `search%3Fq%3Ddeveloper`.